# How would you extract this info from this api?

Tags: javascript, string, express, async-await

I'm kind of new with express, I'm currently working with thedogapi, I am doing the backend and I need to make a GET to an exact part of the api (the temperaments) that's bringing me a lot of problems, an example of the api is:

```
    },
"id": 1,
"name": "Affenpinscher",
"bred_for": "Small rodent hunting, lapdog",
"breed_group": "Toy",
"life_span": "10 - 12 years",
"temperament": "Stubborn, Curious, Playful, Adventurous, Active, Fun-loving",
"origin": "Germany, France",
"reference_image_id": "BJa4kxc4X",
"image": {
"id": "BJa4kxc4X",
"width": 1600,
"height": 1199,
"url": "https://cdn2.thedogapi.com/images/BJa4kxc4X.jpg"
}
```

As you can see, my problem it's that it is only a string with words inside, the thing here would be extracting only the temperaments so I can save them on my database once extracted, but the question is, how could I do that?
I have been trying a few things, but doesn't seems to work...
A code I was trying was

```
const getTemp = await Temperament.findAll()
if (getTemp.length === 0){
  const apiAxios = await axios.get(`https://api.thedogapi.com/v1/breeds?api_key=${API_KEY}`)
  
  const infoToGet = await apiAxios.data?.map(el => {
    console.log(el.temperament?.split(",").map(el => el.trim()).toString())
    return {
      temperament: [el.temperament]?.join().split(",").map(el => el.trim()).toString()
    }
  })
  const dbSave = await 

Temperament.bulkCreate(infoToGet)
}
```

I totally discarded that code since it wasn't achieven what I wanted, but the part of the temperaments was kinda working according to the console log, but still wasn't working, so then I received kind of a reference for help, but this wouldn't make it since it's using array methods... I'll show you (that code bellow should work if it was an array...)

```
router.get("/temperaments", async (req, res) => {
    const temperamentsApi = await axios.get(`https://api.thedogapi.com/v1/breeds?api_key=${API_KEY}`)
    const temperaments = temperamentsApi.data.map( el => el.temperament)
    const tempEach = temperaments.map(el => {
        for (let i = 0; i < el.length; i++) return el[i]})
        console.log(tempEach)
    tempEach.forEach(el => {
        Temperament.findOrCreate({
            where: { temperament: el }
        })
    })

    const allTemperaments = await Temperament.findAll()
    res.send(allTemperaments)
})
```

how would you make this last thing work on the TEMPERAMENT part alone? sorry if it was kinda long, I'm new in all this, and I'm truly stuck here :s

Answer (score 0):

According to the API reference:

https://docs.thedogapi.com/api-reference/breeds/breeds-list

I give you an example for your reference, I refer to your code,
the variable temperamentsApi stores the API result, so the extraction code should be as below.

```js
let result=[];
temperamentsApi.data.forEach(datum=>{
    result.push(datum.temperament);
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: How would you implement it to the code I received as reference? I'm still very confused to where to use the result, also still need to get all to the database once extracted one time the info

Comment: I updated the code, please check.

Comment: const tempEach = temperaments.forEach(datum=>{
                                ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach') 

That's the error it puts me, I already got what to do with the code but it's still bringing me error with these methods

Comment: It should be temperamentsApi.data.forEach, not temperaments.forEach

Comment: Still not working, anyway thank you very much, I don't want to bother all day with this, already helped me a lot with that idea, thanks  :)